# mysql server upgrade problem from 5.0 to 5.1

Tags: mysql

Hi I have upgraded my mysql server from 5.0 to 5.1.

But i am having a problem related to tables for InnoDB storage Engine.

My default engine is InnoDB, So it is enabled in my server.

But tables with InneDB engine are not displaying in phpmyadmin.

Tables with MyISAM are displaying properly.

and also i can't fire a query on the table with InnoDB Engine.

Thanks

Avinash

Answer (score 0):

Have you read through, considered, and followed http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/upgrade.html in absolute detail?

Are you sure the InnoDB engine is enabled in your my.cnf?

What do your logs say?

Answer (score 0):

check your /etc/mysql/my.cnf for a line like:

```
skip-innodb
```

or try:

```
show variables like 'have_innodb';
```

I would imagine innodb was disabled during your upgrade.

Answer (score 0):

The definitive command to check for what storage engines you have available is [SHOW ENGINES](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/show-engines.html). It does sound like InnoDB is disabled for you though.